# Immediate Visualization of MySQL tasks

Tags: php, mysql, verbose

I am using PHP + MySQL. I am inserting 20 Megs of 40000 items via Insert task each day into one data warehouse table.
I need to see the immediate sql task in my PHP script (something like task ticker), but all the 'echos' are written only after the PHP script ends.

Is it possible without using AJAX ?

Or can you recommend me any solution for that ?

I need to show something like that:
INSERT INTO table VALUES (1,2,3);

Comment: Share your code. You need a faster query for insertion?

Comment: Do you need something like: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-processlist.html to show all the active query tastk

Comment: No, i dont need a faster query for insertion. I need to show the current SQL task. The whole script takes about 2 minutes (and is already optimized) and works good.

Comment: If you want to use the show full process list sql query you can get round the ajax by using an iframe that is refreshed periodically

Comment: I need to show only the current task, for example: INSERT INTO table VALUES (1,2,3);

Comment: Again you could do something like: `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE db LIKE 'my_db' AND Info LIKE '$myQuery'` where in this case my query will be the query string that you are currently executing

Comment: Sorry in my last comment in the FROM statment you will have to replace (show full processlist) with INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST

Comment: Thank you guys. I am gonna fight with it.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is echo your $query each time just before you run it.

But I guess you already tried it and failed to see it work directly.

This could be because php or your web server is buffering the output until the entire request is complete.

You can do the following to prevent the buffering:

- use `flush()` after the echo that needs to be echoed to directly
- don't use `ob_start()` and turn on implicit flushing because even without ob_start php might to implicit buffering
- don't use compression.

you can try to fiddle with these commands:

```
apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
ini_set('output_buffering', 0);
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);
```

Comment: Interesting possible solution, i am going to try it. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, what webserver are you using? Apache? If IIS, you also need some IIS settings changed.